# spark stream based deduplication

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have started to play with Spark, And i know this is not a place to ask this question. But still hope to get answer.

I want to do hash based comparison to find duplicate records. 
Record which i receive from stream will have hashid,recordid field in it.

1. I want to have all the historic records (hashid, recordid --> key,value) in memory RDD
2. When a new record is received in spark DStream RDD i want to compare against the historic records (hash, recordid)
3. also add the new records into existing historic records (hashid, recordid --> key,value) in memory RDD

My thoughts:

1. join the time based RDD and cache them in memory (historic lookup)
2. compare the new RDD comes, foreach record compare againt the historic lookup

What I have done:

1. I  have created a stream line and able to consume the records.
2. But i am not sure how to store it in memory

I have the following questions:

1. How can i achieve this or workaround ?
2. Can i do this using MLib? or spark stream fits for my usecase ?

**update:**

I will receive  on time T1 and  on time T2. in that case on time T2 the r2 is deuplicate of r1. I wanted to get that id or r1 as the recordid.

Comment: Use Bloom filter / filters?

Comment: @zero323 Looks like he also wants to store the key value pairs. He may need a stateful stream. How would you go about implementing a bloomsfilter inside a streaming graph?

Comment: Hi @zero323, Yes i am using the bloom filter based implementation in PRD but the problem is, I want to get the recordid. Say I will receive <h1,r1> on time T1 and <h1,r2>  on time T2. in that case on time T2 the r2 is deuplicate of r1. I wanted to get that id.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Yes you are correct

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov You can use stateful stream to store certain amount of bloom filters.(enough to get desired parallelization and guarantees). Then you can use `mapWithState` as usual. Not ideal but IMHO beats any attempt to keep a whole history in memory.

Comment: @zero323 But how would you partition the bloom filters? `mapWithState` needs a key to partition by, what would you use as a key to reach the right filter? Maybe you could arbitrary select X bloom filters and then do `(hash, record) % X` to always get the "right" one. But then you'd be doing half the bloom filters job prior to bloom filtering :P

Comment: Yeah, this was an idea :) We would do half of the job indeed but keeping constant memory footprint and higher guarantees (less false positives) as long as hashing functions are well chosen.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  Please check my update also in the question.